# validations of text box in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to do one validation in javascript.
I have text box into which user should not allow to enter value which is more that 5.00
means user can enter value which is less than 5.00.
so please suggest such validation in javascript

Comment: There is a good jQuery validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

```
var textboxObj = document.getElementById("textbox");
if(parseFloat(textboxObj.value) <= 5){ // to ensure user has entered only numbers
    alert("success");
}else {
    alert("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: simple approach is the best, but you'll want to check for `NaN` (Not A Number) as well, otherwise any non-numeric input may register as success.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function val()
{
    var text=document.getElementById("text").value;
    if(isNaN(text)==true || text=="" || text>=5)
    {
        alert("Please Insert Digits only Which is Less Than 5");
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>    
<form>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return val()" />
</form>
```